# Docker volume key with 1 parameter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

Why has volumes key only 1 parameter ? "/sessions"
As I know volumes key must have 2 parameter, for example this could be valid:

```
foldername:/sessions
```

But I see only 1 parameter.

```
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "30002:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=something
      - PMA_PORT= 3306
    volumes:
      - /sessions
```

I was reading this tutorial:

https://www.myonlineedu.com/blog/view/13/build-docker-container-for-php-7-and-mysql-based-application

Answer (score 1):

This is called [**short syntax**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3)

```yaml
volumes:
  # 1. Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # 2. Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # 3. Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # 4. User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # 5. Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

So you are asking about (1), which means you just need to specify the **container path**, and let's the engine (docker daemon) create the volume.